# Python. Как отсортировать словарь внутри словаря по ключам?

Tags: python

Существует словарь с ключами которые обозначают ID. Внутри каждого словаря еще словарь с ключами ID который представляет ключ внешнего словаря и USERS который представляет лист кортежей.

```
example = {
    '010': {
        ID: '010',
        USERS: [('Albert', 'Nolan')]'},
    '002': {
        ID: '002',
        USERS: [('Ginger', 'Bread'), ('Deus', 'Bexs')]},
    '999': {
        ID: '999',
        USERS: [('Pede', 'Kordo'), ('Deus', 'Bexs'), 
                  ('Bister', 'Stre')]},
    '021': {
        ID: '021',
        USERS: [('Pede', 'Kordo'), ('Bister', 'Stre')]},    
    '015': {
        ID: '015',
        USERS: []}
}
```

Нужно создать функцию которая будет сортировать словарь по юзерам и ID к которым они привязаны.

Пример сортировки:

```
sort_by_user = {
    ('Pede', 'Kordo'):['004', '999'],
    ('Bister', 'Stre'): ['004', '999'],
    ('Deus', 'Bexs'): ['002', '999'],
    ('Albert', 'Nolan'): ['010'],
    ('Ginger', 'Bread'): ['002']
}
```

Помогите найти ошибки в коде ниже чтобы users_to_ids совпадал с sort_by_user

```
#Создание листа юзеров в алфавитном порядке [(USERS)]
users_list = [] 
for key in example:
        if len(example[key][USERS]) == 1:
            l.append(example[key][USERS][0])
        elif len(example[key][USERS]) > 1:
            for n in range(len(example[key][USERS])):
                l.append(example[key][USERS][n])
        elif len(example[key][USERS]) == 0:
            None
#Удаление повторений в листе
    if users_list:
        users_list.sort()
        last = users_list[-1]
        for i in range(len(users_list)-2, -1, -1):
            if last == users_list[i]:
                del users_list[i]
            else:
                last = users_list[i]
#создание словаря {'ID': [(USERS)]}
ids_to_users = {}
for key in example:
        ids_to_users [key] = example[key][USERS]

users_to_ids = {}
for key in ids_to_users :
        for item in users_list:
            if item in ids_to_users [key]:
                 users_to_ids[item] = users_to_ids.get(item, []) + [key]

print(users_to_ids)
{('Albert', 'Nolan'): ['010'], ('Deus', 'Bexs'): ['999'], ('Ginger', 'Bread'): ['002'], ('Bister', 'Stre'): ['021'], ('Pede', 'Kordo'): ['021']}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что под ключ USERS не попадают все ID которые совпадают

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо всего-лишь вместо

```
                users_to_ids[item] = key
```

написать

```
                users_to_ids[item] = users_to_ids.get(item, []) + [key]
```

---

Привожу на ваш же пример чтобы вы сами удостоверились, что это работает. *(код местами подсокращён, но на содержимое переменных это не влияет)*

```
ID = 'id'
USERS = 'users'
example = {
    '010': {
        ID: '010',
        USERS: [('Albert', 'Nolan')]},
    '002': {
        ID: '002',
        USERS: [('Ginger', 'Bread'), ('Deus', 'Bexs')]},
    '999': {
        ID: '999',
        USERS: [('Pede', 'Kordo'), ('Deus', 'Bexs'), 
                  ('Bister', 'Stre')]},
    '021': {
        ID: '021',
        USERS: [('Pede', 'Kordo'), ('Bister', 'Stre')]},    
    '015': {
        ID: '015',
        USERS: []}
}

#Создание листа юзеров в алфавитном порядке [(USERS)]
users_list = sum((item[USERS] for item in example.values()), [])
#Удаление повторений в листе
users_list = sorted(set(users_list))
#создание словаря {'ID': [(USERS)]}
ids_to_users = {item[ID]:item[USERS] for item in example.values()}

users_to_ids = {}
for item in example.values():
    for user in item[USERS]:
        users_to_ids[user] = users_to_ids.get(user, []) + [item[ID]]

print(users_to_ids)
```

```
{('Albert', 'Nolan'): ['010'],
 ('Ginger', 'Bread'): ['002'],
 ('Deus', 'Bexs'): ['002', '999'],
 ('Pede', 'Kordo'): ['999', '021'],
 ('Bister', 'Stre'): ['999', '021']}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но вместо 
sort_by_user = {
    ('Pede', 'Kordo'):['004', '999'],
    ('Bister', 'Stre'): ['004', '999'],
    ('Deus', 'Bexs'): ['002', '999'],
    ('Albert', 'Nolan'): ['010'],
    ('Ginger', 'Bread'): ['002']
}
у меня выходит
sort_by_user = {('Albert', 'Nolan'): ['010'], ('Deus', 'Bexs'): ['999'], ('Ginger', 'Bread'): ['002'], ('Bister', 'Stre'): ['021'], ('Pede', 'Kordo'): ['021']}

Comment: Я на вашем коде (если заменить строчку на мою) получаю вот это - `{('Albert', 'Nolan'): ['010'], ('Deus', 'Bexs'): ['002', '999'], ('Ginger', 'Bread'): ['002'], ('Bister', 'Stre'): ['999', '021'], ('Pede', 'Kordo'): ['999', '021']}`.

Comment: Извиняюсь, в первоначальном коде была ошибка. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: `users_to_ids[user] = users_to_ids.get(user, []) + [item[ID]]` -> `users_to_ids.setdefault(user, []).append(item[ID])`.